# Testing devise with shoulda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing, shoulda, devise

I'm having some difficulties in testing devise with shoulda:

```
2) Error:
test: handle :index logged as admin should redirect to Daily page.
(Admin::DailyClosesControllerTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
devise (1.0.6) [v] lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:52:in
`setup_controller_for_warden'
```

I have this in my test_helper:

```
include Devise::TestHelpers
```

Thoughts ?
Thanks in advance,

Cristi

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`include Devise::TestHelpers` doesn't go in the test_helper.rb file, but rather inside the scope of the individual testing classes. Just like their README shows:

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure if rspeicher is fully correct, but putting:

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

at the very bottom of test_helper.rb (yes after the `END` of the `class ActiveSupport::TestCase`) should work.  It has for 3 or 4 projects of mine so far, including one i'm working on today.

You then can use `sign_in users(:one)` if you are using fixtures, in your tests.  Unless shoulda is messing it up?

Comment: That's different. He was just putting "include Devise::TestHelpers" in the base scope of his test_helper.rb file, not scoped inside the TestCase class.

Comment: That is precisely what the README says to do.

Comment: +1 for "yes after the END of the class ActiveSupport::TestCase"