# Making functional tests in Rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, functional-testing, devise

After 3 years of procrastination today is the day that I start testing my Rails apps. My first step is to fix the failing tests in my Rails 3 beta4 app.

My last 3 failing tests have to do with the devise gem and its authenticate_user! method in a before_filter at the top of my controller.

You'd earn great karma by helping me out with this since it will enable me to use the TDD methodology from now on.

Here is the error that troubles me:

```
1) Error:
test_should_get_accepted(ModerationControllerTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate!' for nil:NilClass
    /test/functional/moderation_controller_test.rb:10:in `test_should_get_accepted'
```

Devise just gives functional tests pointers and helpers in this page: http://github.com/plataformatec/devise but I just don't know how to put this into application.

Can you please give this testing noob some detailed instructions on how to use these helpers?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It took me a while but I found the way. Here it is for anyone stuck at the same point:

At the top of the moderation_controller_test.rb, below the class declaration, add this line:

```
include Devise::TestHelpers
```

I have 2 records in my user fixture and I added this line within each test where the user has to be authorized to perform the action.

```
sign_in User.first
```

Of course it's dead simple once you know how to do it.

Comment: It created other errors to include Devise::TestHelpers in test_helper.rb file. According to this answer it should only be included in individual test files : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839328/testing-devise-with-shoulda So i edited your answer

Comment: the problem is not with putting it in test_helper.rb per se.  The problem is if it is not scoped correctly - it must be in the class ActionController::TestCase.  If it is included in the ActiveSupport::TestCase block in test_helper.rb, things get ugly.

Answer (score 19):

If you want the Devise test helpers to be available to all of your tests, you have to enclose the include mentioned by allesklar at the bottom of `test_helper.rb` in a class declaration like this:

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

**Update:  01.25.2017**

... rails 5 posts a DEPRECATION WARNING & asks you use ...

`Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers`

Answer (score 7):

I'm relatively new to Rails, so I'd like to add a couple things that may not be obvious to other new folks.

Concerning the user fixture, I had to define one but leave it empty in order for this to work:

```
# in users.yml    
joe: {}
```

When using the devise `sign_in` helper, you can access the hash object directly in your test:

```
# a test method in some_controller_test.rb
sign_in users(:joe)
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures for more information on Rails fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting verbatim from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise:

> If you're using RSpec, you can put the following inside a file named `spec/support/devise.rb`:
>
> > `RSpec.configure do |config|`
> >
> > `config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller`
> >
> > `end`

You can now use `sign_in` and `sign_out` in your RSpec tests.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the code in the test_helpers.rb, I added this at the top of the controller_test and it worked for me:

```
require 'test_helper'
```