# Rails Devise testhelpers: sign_in is working with get but not post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

I'm working on functionality testing on a Rails website that uses Devise, and I've run into a strange problem. I needed to figure out how to simulate a login, and after a little searching, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187287/making-functional-tests-in-rails-with-devise) that told me about Devise::TestHelpers and the sign_in function. Oddly enough, though, it's working in some but not all of my tests. Here's a couple of my tests:

```
include Devise::TestHelpers

setup do
  @game = games(:game_one)
  @user = users(:one)
  sign_in(@user)
end

# This test passes
test "should get index" do
  get :index
  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:games)
end

# This test fails; the post redirects to /users/sign_in
# as if accessed without logging in
test "should create game" do
  assert_difference('Game.count') do
    post :create, game: { name: @game.name }
  end

  assert_redirected_to game_path(assigns(:game))
end
```

And the controller itself looks like this:

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # Some mostly-autogenerated CRUD
end
```

From what I can tell, the main difference between the tests that are working and the tests that think I haven't logged in is that the former are using `get` and the latter `post`. Is that something that makes sense? And how can I fix it?

Edit: Is this something to do with the "scope" that the Devise readme mentions? It doesn't really explain what that means, but it seems like it may be relevant.

Comment: I would check your logs. Make sure it's not complaining about the authenticity token, or something else fishy with the request.

Comment: @farleyknight: Good call. It's not getting valid CSRF tokens, which apparently is okay for GET requests but not any other type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Thanks to farleyknight's comment, I discovered it was complaining about CSRF token authenticity. From there, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177218/cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-when-testing-emberjs-rails-devise-app-usi) had a working solution. I added this to my ApplicationController:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token if Rails.env.test?
```

There's probably a way to actually send valid CSRF tokens as part of the test, which would probably be a better solution, but this one's working for me.

Comment: You could add this to your `config/environments/test.rb` file: `config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false`